# Microsoft Translator Hub with dictionary file only

Tags: microsoft-translator

I have setup a Microsoft Translator Hub system to treat some specific words on my webpage (like company name etc) with a custom translation using a dictionary *.xlsx sheet.

But i am not able to train + deploy the system, because it forces me to upload at least 2.000 parallel sentences to start a training.

I only want it to use the few words i've added in the dictionary sheet. All other translation should be use the default translation system.

Documentation says: *"You can start with as little as one dictionary entry. The custom category you create with your dictionary can be built on top of the general or the standard (speech or tech) categories..."*

But there is no way to clone the general of a standard category and build upon it.

So what am i missing here? Who can i deploy a system with just one dictionary file?

Answer (score 1):

the ability to build a system with a dictionary only depends on the language pair you are customizing for. Not all language pairs that the API exposes have an underlying language pair.

The details are explained in this article:
https://cognitive.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/1166938-hub-building-a-custom-system-using-a-dictionary-o

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I followed the guidelines mentioned in the link. I uploaded a dictionary for "de" to "ru" containing 12 words only, unselected all files from training tab. But when i try to deploy it an alert window says: **Please add/select testing, tuning, training dataset documents before conducting the training.** I am not able to submit the dictionary only.

Comment: German to Russian has no underlying Microsoft system, so the training data you provide is the only training material.
You can work around this by creating a German-English and an English-Russian system with the same parameters, and provide two dictionaries.

Comment: Hi, Just want to ask over here if anyone could help, if i use dictionary to preserve word from being translated from english to korean, then inside my excel, for the first row i will add the language code and the second row for example under en column, i add 'Back' and under ko, i should add 'Back' also right? Then all i need to do is just upload the xlsx, checked it and train it and the BLEU result should not be 0.00 right? Im having a problem with this. I used the same step but my BLEU score is 0.00. Any idea what i did wrong?

Comment: If you supply only a dictionary, there is no test set to calculate the BLEU score with. You can test this only with real calls to the Translator API.